# Using a swear word filter with InStr in Visual Basic 2012

Tags: vba

I want to compare the IF argument to a string array. The user will try to put in a teamname into a textbox, if the user uses a swear word anywhere within that textbox, it will display an error message and clear the textbox. If the user has not sworn, it will register the teamname and carry on with the program (As can be seen in the 2nd IF statement). I have tried to get this code to work for a week now and cannot get it to work.

```
Private Sub SelectionButtonEnter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SelectionButtonEnter.Click
    Dim HasSworn As Boolean = False
    Dim swears() As String = {"Fuck", "fuck", "Shit", "shit", "Shite", "shite", "Dick", "dick", "Pussy", "pussy", "Piss", "piss", "Vagina", "vagina", "Faggot", "faggot"} 'Declare potential swear words the kids can use
    For Each swear As String In swears
        If InStr(SelectionTextBoxTeamName.Text, swear) > 0 Then
            SelectionTextBoxTeamName.Clear() 'Clear the textbox
            MessageBox.Show("Remember ... You can be disqualified, raise your hand and Blair will set up the program for you again") 'Let the user know they have entered a swear word and ask them to select another team name
        End If
        If Not InStr(SelectionTextBoxTeamName.Text, swear) > 0 Then
            Timer1.Enabled = True 'Enable timer 1 for the learn box
            Timer3ForSelection.Enabled = True 'Enable this timer to show the learn button
            TeamName = SelectionTextBoxTeamName.Text() 'Once this button has been pressed, store the content of that textbox in a the TeamName string 
            SelectionLabelTeamName.Text = "Welcome " & SelectionTextBoxTeamName.Text & " Please click 'Learn' in the box below to begin" 'Display the contents of the string along with other text here
            SelectionLabelTeamNameTL.Text() = "Team Name: " & TeamName 'Display the contents of the string along with other text here
            SelectionTextBoxTeamName.BackColor = Color.Green 'Have the back color of the box set to green
            SelectionTextBoxTeamName.Enabled = False 'Do not allow the user/users enter another team name
        End If
    Next 'A next must be declared in a for each statement
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I'd approach it that way; if the user types f**kyou, your code wouldn't catch it.  How about this instead:

In your code:

```
If ContainsBannedWord(SelectionTextBoxTeamName.Text) Then
   Msgbox "Hold out your hand, bad person. SlapSlapSlap"
Else
   Msgbox "Good boy!"
End if

Function ContainsBannedWord(sInput As String) As Boolean

    Dim aBannedWords(1 To 5) As String
    Dim x As Long

    ' Make all the banned words capitalized
    aBannedWords(1) = "BANNED1"
    aBannedWords(2) = "BANNED2"
    aBannedWords(3) = "BANNED3"
    aBannedWords(4) = "BANNED4"
    aBannedWords(5) = "BANNED5"

    For x = LBound(aBannedWords) To UBound(aBannedWords)
        If InStr(UCase(sInput), aBannedWords(x)) > 0 Then
            ContainsBannedWord = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    ContainsBannedWord = False

End Function
```